# Is it possible to automate the testing of a dynamically generated PDF file from a web application?

Tags: automation, webautomation

I see that it is possible to extract the text and images from a PDF file and test them. What I really want is to automate the testing of some tables with indefinite data in the PDF file which will be generated by the application. The generated PDF file can also be a report with data extracted from many tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think [PDFUtil](http://www.testautomationguru.com/introducing-pdfutil-to-compare-pdf-files-extract-resources/) is your solution to solve the problem

Comment: I get this solution. But what I want is compare the files data wise. The PDFs that I want to test has data in Tables, separate headers and different sections. So, is it possible to get the data of a specific cell in a table in PDF or under a specific section/header? And to test it/compare it? Visual comparison can be considered provided the PDF file generated is the same every time which is not in my case.